# Identify a movie featuring a mechanical spider

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

I would like to know this movie title. Unfortunately, I only remember a little about this movie plot.

I watched it around 2008. I think it's an action adventure film. The only plot I remember is a big mechanical-like spider in a background of a desert/barren/wasteland. Some guys in the movie are wearing a round western hat. There's also a scene in a prison where a guy is able to bend the prison iron bar with a wet rag. I think there's also a scene with a zeppelin (not sure).

It's in color and not animated. It's in English and probably a Hollywood movie.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Sounds like [Wild Wild West](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120891/?ref_=nv_sr_1) which was released in 1999 and starred Will Smith and Kevin Kline and was a Steam Punk Western.

It featured a large mechanical spider

[image: Wild Wild West spider]

Comment: For some reason, the image is fail to be opened in my browser :(

Comment: If you search on the internet for "wild wild west spider" you'll find plenty of alternate images. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wild+wild+west+spider

Comment: As others mentioned the answer is Wild Wild West. However I just wanted to add that the prison bar scene may have been Shanghai Noon, and you might be mixing these up.

Comment: By the way, Kevin Smith has a great story about working on a Superman screenplay that gives some, well, incredible background on the giant spider in Wild Wild West: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo2KB1dEDdk

Comment: There's also a smaller mechanical spider, used as the bad guy's wheelchair, if I remember correctly?

Comment: @JanDvorak I recall that "walking chair" (rather than "wheelchair") too, and even found a GIF:  http://i.imgur.com/UnSl6xn.gif